# linq query insert exist query string into linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to make the query follow the query string of the website but it cant be done in this way, is there any other option to do something like this? For example i can insert name,type,class in the query string but not every variable is need to search for the student

```
      if (Request.QueryString["Name"] != null)
        {
            name = Request.QueryString["Name"];
            query += "WHERE c.Name == " + name + " ";
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["Type"] != null)
        {
            type += Request.QueryString["Type"];
            query += "WHERE c.type == "+ type + " ";
        }


        string querytest = query
        var q = "from c in db.Students" + query + "select c";
        GridView1.DataSource = q;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (elaborate on can't be done (errors?). Then check the blanks in your resulting query string;)

Comment: It's not clear what type of data framework you're using. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to ask question SO, i had search SO for many question but i found no solution, so i try to ask here. Is data framework something like linq query? sorry i don't get what mean of data framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
        var query = from c in db.Students select c;
        if (Request.QueryString["Name"] != null)
        {
            name = Request.QueryString["Name"];
            query = query.Where(c => c.name == name);
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["Type"] != null)
        {
            type += Request.QueryString["Type"];
            query = query.Where(c => c.type == type);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think Where(c => c.name == name); is what excactly i need.